# Sync local repo with GitHub

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm completely new to git. I have a repo on GitHub that I downloaded on my system and made changes to the project. Now I want to push those changes to gitHub. I did not sync this local copy using Git but just downloaded a copy from GitHub(zip). I tried this:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'local changes'
git remote add origin 'url to github repo'
git remote -v
git push origin master
```

After last step, it says I do not have remote repo on my system and changes have been rejected. What needs to be done here?

Comment: For future reference, the usual workflow is that you pull a branch from GitHub, work on it, then commit and push those changes back.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I know I made a mistake. But the changes on local copy need to be pushed now. I can start afresh, but I want to solve, learn this situation. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get around this problem immediately would be to properly pull the `master` branch from GitHub, and then cherry pick the commit corresponding to the work you just did:

```
git remote add origin 'url to github repo'
git pull origin master
git checkout master
git cherry-pick <SHA-1 of commit you just made>
git commit -m 'Made a change to the master branch'
git push origin master
```

To find out the `<SHA-1>` hash of the commit you just made, you can checkout the local branch where you did your work, and type `git status`.  Find the commit you want, and use its `<SHA-1>` hash.  And you should probably delete the first branch you created.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a local repo, and want to sync it with remote, it's really easy :

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/reponame.git
git push -u origin master
```